# CSS Margin not working properly in IE and Safari

Tags: css, margin

Am building a CSS menu and for some reason the margin of the sub menu shows different in IOS and IE 11.

Bellow is some pictures & css code

Thats how it should look like and how it show in chrome.
[image: This is how it should look like in all the browsers]

This is how IE & IOS safari shows, the margin should be higher from up and should be less to the left.
[image: Internet Explorer]

Here is the code

```
header .left li .mega-menu {
    background-color: #31342a;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin:-50px 0px 0px 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /** Firefox */
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /** For Opera */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0.1s linear 0.1s,opacity 0.5s linear, margin 0.5s;
    z-index: -1;
}

header .left li:hover > .mega-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    transition-delay:0s;
}
```

Comment: Please specify explorer version.

Comment: I just updated. Its 11

Comment: `.mega-menu` is absolutely positioned, but there are no offsets shown in your CSS snippet.  Also, is there a parent/ancestor element with `position: relative` to define a reference for positioning `.mega-menu`, otherwise, the default is the viewport.  You need to post more CSS and HTML, the devil is in the details.

Comment: Am going to host it so you guys can have a look. @MarcAudet header is the parent and its position is set as relative. I'll post the link in a minute

Comment: Is there a link to this page?

Comment: The problem is fixed, thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this.
I think you have missed `display:block;`

```
header .left li .mega-menu {
    background-color: #31342a;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    margin:-50px 0px 0px 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /** Firefox */
    -o-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /** For Opera */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0.1s linear 0.1s,opacity 0.5s linear, margin 0.5s;
    z-index: -1;
display:block;
}

header .left li:hover > .mega-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    transition-delay:0s;
}
```